# I'm currently reading "Automate boring stuffs with Python" and I dont know why my auto add logo and resize image project doesnt work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm new to code. So, to be honest, I dont know what I do wrong here

```
import os
from PIL import Image

SQUARE_FIT_SIZE = 900
LOGO_FILENAME = "24h.png"

logo = Image.open(LOGO_FILENAME)
logoWidth, logoHeight = logo.size

os.makedirs("withLogo", exist_ok=True)

path = "/Users/mac/Desktop/水/71"
for filename in os.listdir("path"):

    if not (filename.endswith('.png') or filename.endswith('.jpg')) \
            or filename == LOGO_FILENAME:
        im = Image.open(filename)
        width, height = im.size
        if width > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE and height > SQUARE_FIT_SIZE:
            if width>height:
                height = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / width) * height)
                width = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
            else:
                width = int((SQUARE_FIT_SIZE / height) * width)
                height = SQUARE_FIT_SIZE
            print('Resizing %s...' % (filename))
            im = im.resize((width, height))

print('Adding logo to %s...' % filename)
im.paste(logo, (width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight), logo)

im.save(os.path.join('withLogo', filename))
```

I expect the output will be a folder of added logo and resized images, but nothing happens as the code doesnt work.

Comment: _but nothing happens as the code doesnt work._ --> Do you get any errors? Please [edit] your question to get the code formatting right, which is a very important aspect of python. Oh, and check your hard drive, it might be that the files are saved in an unexpected place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and computer programming. One of the skills you need to develop as you learn how to code is debugging your code. As a professional, I probably spend more time debugging than I do writing new code, so this is incredibly important. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started. When something doesn't work the way you expect, these are the things you need to do to figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with your code:

1. You are using relative paths. So instead of

   ```
   os.makedirs("withLogo", exist_ok=True)
   path = "/Users/mac/Desktop/水/71"
   ```

   reverse the order of the statements and use an absolute path for `makedirs`:

   ```
   path = "/Users/mac/Desktop/水/71"
   target_path=os.path.join(path, "withLogo")
   os.makedirs(target_path, exist_ok=True)
   ```

   I also added a new variable `target_path` that you can use later when you save your image:

   ```
    im.save(os.path.join(target_path, filename))
   ```

   If you are using relative paths your current working directory is used as root for all these operations.
2. You are using a string instead of a variable:

   ```
   for filename in os.listdir("path"):
   ```

   No need for quotes here, so this is easy to fix:

   ```
   for filename in os.listdir(path):
   ```

With these hints it should be easy for you to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last 3 lines:

```
print('Adding logo to %s...' % filename)
im.paste(logo, (width - logoWidth, height - logoHeight), logo)

im.save(os.path.join('withLogo', filename))
```

are not indented properly. They should be inside of the for loop (4 spaces or 1 tab over). Instances of the images that the logo is being pasted on are defined within the for loop with `im = Image.open(filename)`, so since `im.paste` and `im.save` are called outside of the loop, they're referencing something that doesn't exist.